# VScode build recipe with keybinding

Tags: pdftex, vscode

I have VScode and LaTeX workshop and usually compile by typing ctrl-alt-B. This does the full run (pdflatex, bibtex, 2 x pdflatex). However, I am often happy with just one LaTeX run, so I have added a matching recipe and have put `latex-workshop.recipes` on a keybinding, but then I still have to select *which* recipe I want to use. I guess that I can code that into the keybinding's `args` parameter, but so far that produced errors.  Right now I have

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+h",
    "command": "latex-workshop.recipes",
    "args": [
        "onelatex"
    ]
}
```

If I now press the key, it does the full run and complains: `Failed to resolve build recipe: onelatex`. How to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the string directly as args, not in a list.

```
{
    "key": "Ctrl+Alt+H",
    "when": "resourceExtname == .tex",
    "command": "latex-workshop.recipes",
    "args": "onelatex"
}
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Yes, lovely. That's what I needed!