# latex file wont compile if I add bib file but will compile same file without it

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

My code won't compile with my `jobname.bib` file. It says `Biber reported the following issues (biblatex)  with 'UniEconomicSocialCouncil2009': (biblatex)  - Entry 'UniEconomicSocialCouncil2009' (textest.bib): Invalid format '2009' of date field 'date' - ignoring.` However it will compile file without it. I asked a question here [Citation 'xxx' on pg 'xx' undefined on input line 'xx'; empty bibliography on input line ; there were undefined references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598105/citation-xxx-on-pg-xx-undefined-on-input-line-xx-empty-bibliography-on-in) and answer I accepted gave me some settings to put into my VSCode LaTeX workshop setup to make it work (pdflatex + biblatex + pdfLateX x 2). It worked initially. Now it does not work. This is strange because I have not changed anything in the bib file. I singled out one for the purpose tests. Now it has issues with the date as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
   @InProceedings{UniEconomicSocialCouncil2009,
   author      = {{United Nations. Economic Commission for Africa} and {United Nations. Economic and Social Council}},
   title       = {The transport situaiton in {A}frica},
   publisher   = {UN. ECA},
   date        = {2009},
   eventdate   = {2009-10-13/2009-10-15},
   eventtitle  = {UN. ECA committee on Trade, Regional Cooperation and Integration (6th Session: 2009, Oct. 13-15: Addis Ababa, Ethiopia)},
   location    = {Addis Ababa, Ethiopia},
   shortauthor = {UNECA and UNESC},
   url         = {http://hdl.handle.net/10855/3252},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{UniEconomicSocialCouncil2009}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: you have posted a lot of code but no one can run it to see the problem so it doesn't really help. Make a small self containted but complete document that shows the problem. (just move the \cite to your main document checking that you get the same issue then  delete tthe subfile references and any packages not used in the example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. I have edited the question. Is it better now?

Comment: well it's stil _far_ from minimal (do you really need tikz and  palatino fonts to show a problem with biblatex?, think of people running this code with tracing enabled,  adding dozens of packages and 10s of thousands of lines of additional code does not help anyone debug if they are not needed)  and it gives errors when I tried it missing preamble.sty

Comment: I also get ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> filec@ntents@checkdir reference ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have achieved the same with this MWE. Please take a look.

Comment: `date = {2009},` is perfectly correct and in fact your example compiles fine for me. I'm guessing this is a problem with Biber's cache. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/541486/35864 for more details. Delete the cache as explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864 and try again. Do **not** stop the subsequent Biber run even if it takes much longer than usual. Biber needs to unpack into the cache on the first run. If that process is stopped prematurely the cache might be damaged again.

Comment: @Spirit_bird thanks for making the small example, moewe knows a lot more about biblatex than me, do what it says above:-)